# Wine (Windows Apps Interfacing Software) Installer Wants To Remove Unrelated Apps

Tags: wine

I need to use a Windows interfacing package on Ubuntu since I want to run Affinity Designer  and the latter only runs natively on MacOS and Windows.

Following [this procedure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wx8NbZEAPNM) (or indeed using the Synaptic package manager) you reach a point where the installer asks permission to REMOVE the following packages and it then lists a long range of other Wine-unrelated applications on my PC:

*apparmor-utils cheese deja-dup eog evince gdbserver git gnome-calendar
gparted inkscape iwd libc6-dbg libdvdcss-dev libdvdcss2 libevdocument3-4
libevview3-3 libnetplan0 libreoffice-calc libreoffice-gnome
libreoffice-gtk3 libssl-dev linux-headers-5.4.0-59-generic
linux-headers-5.8.0-55-generic lshw mesa-utils microsoft-edge-beta
mysql-workbench-community netplan.io nodejs openjdk-14-jdk
openjdk-14-jdk-headless openjdk-14-jre openjdk-14-jre-headless
opera-stable orca powertop python3-apparmor python3-brlapi
python3-libapparmor rsyslog shotwell simple-scan snapd strace
swi-prolog-nox thermald tmux ubuntu-advantage-tools ubuntu-minimal
ubuntu-standard uuid-runtime xbrlapi*

Obviously I cannot delete hardly any of these applications (some are hardware drivers in fact) let alone all of them !

Can anyone with Wine experience explain the reason for this odd request ?

Do all of these apps depend on something vital to Wine or what ?

Let me be clear: I only want to run Affinity via Wine. All other apps - regardless of whether Wine can run them or not - will be run via Ubuntu 20.04.

[image: Original Output]

## EDIT

I've added a screenshot of output when using the apt install command with a debug option. No advance on why an installation is interfering with existing installations and recommending removal of packages.

[image: Output With Debug]

Comment: That would explain why it wouldn't install. But it says nothing as to why it asks to remove wholly separate packages . . .

Comment: Well, **sudo apt install --debug wine** and **sudo apt --debug install wine** are not understood. I looked here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/570680/how-can-i-enable-verbose-output-in-apt  and used a command that told em nothing much extra.

Comment: OK. I've been on the Wine Linux Forum and Wine was only installable on my system via a 64-bit only manual install. However I could not run the app (Affinity-Designer) I wanted to on this. All indications here https://forum.affinity.serif.com/index.php?/topic/94180-running-affinity-on-linux-finally-works/  suggest that nobody else has productively ran Affinity on Wine either. So it looks like the only viable way to get Affinity on Linux is by a virtual box on the disk . . .

Comment: The developers and testers of Wine seem to [agree with your assessment](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=17927). Regardless, you should still fix your system -- most of the apt-related problems that you encountered seem unlikely to be Wine-specific.

Comment: @user535733   I have followed sets of commands available on Google for this but found no package breaks. if you have a better procedure, please share.

Comment: Your question is about why-installing-Wine-causes-problems, not about basic maintenance. If you want to know about basic maintenance, please obey the guidelines of this site and ask a new, clean question.